# Can I execute behavior on an ASP.NET foreign key property setter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In the following situation:

```
    [ForeignKey("GenericFK")]
    public GenericFK GenericFK { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to insert behavior into the setter? Such as

```
set{
    GenericFK = value;
    functionCallWhenthisChanges();
}
```

As a WPF guy, I'm used to having dependency properties and the ability to have callbacks tied to properties so I can have behavior execute the moment a property is updated. Is it possible for me to do anything of the sort in ASP.NET MVC5.1? A simple, hey this FK updated, execute behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> As a WPF guy

That is "as a WPF guy that never learned C# basics"?

> public GenericFK GenericFK { get; set; }

This is an auto property, and nothing can be inserted into an auto property.

BUT: you can make it a normal property by standard .NET rules. I.e. you can implement get and set yourself, storing the value in a variable.

BUT: When EF loads the data (and seriously, your code has nothing to do with ASP.NET at all - get your technologies proper) then the set exectes when data is LOADED, too... making this a little hard.